# Javascript XMLHttpRequest Domain Issue

Tags: javascript

I've rewritten this question as it turns out I was asking the wrong thing!  I have a script that runs on page load:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {         
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)  //4=finished, 200=ok
    {      
      alert("this doesn't show");
      //document.getElementById("category_content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","content.php",false);
  xmlhttp.send();

</script>
```

The page it runs on is a subdomain and has a url like so:
http://dev.mywebsite.co.uk/category/product-category

A .htaccess file is used to make the url "pretty".  The actual url is:
http://dev.mywebsite.co.uk/category.php

The alert in the code doesn't appear when either of the 2 addresses above are used.

However if I use this url:
http://thegiftguru.co.uk/dev/category.php

The alert pops up.  This is quite confusing as I assumed dev. and /dev was the same thing.

category.php and category_content.php are in the **same** folder.

Is there any way to get the XMLHttpRequest working with such a setup? The error I get is:

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/dev/category_content.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

category_content.php is simply:

```
echo "hello";
```

And it works fine when loaded directly

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html) site, it will show you how to enable CORS using PHP.